# memdiacodec decoder working on android 5.0 but not on android 4.4

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec

i am trying to decode h264 stream use MediaCodec on Android.

i use `csd-0`, `csd-1` to set `sps` and `pps` like this.

```
MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", sps);
format.setByteBuffer("csd-1", pps);
```

i configure the decoder with output surface to render the output data.

```
decoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
```

then, i just start a thread to decode the data i received from the network using this loop.

```
while (running) {
    if (!isEOS) {
        int inIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
        if (inIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inIndex];
            byte[] data = getVideoPacket(); // native method that get data from network
            buffer.put(data);

            decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, data.length, 0L, 0);
        }
    }

    int outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 10000);
    switch (outIndex) {
        case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
            Log.d("DecodeActivity", "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
            outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
            break;
        case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
            Log.d("DecodeActivity", "New format " + decoder.getOutputFormat());
            MediaFormat format = decoder.getOutputFormat();
            break;
        case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
            Log.d("DecodeActivity", "dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!");
            break;
        default:
            ByteBuffer buffer = outputBuffers[outIndex];
            Log.v("DecodeActivity", "We can't use this buffer but render it due to the API limit, " + buffer);

            decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true); // render
            break;
    }

    if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "OutputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
        break;
    }
}
```

note that i use `0` for presentationTimestamp of `queueInputBuffer` since the data i got is from network socket, and i don't know how to compute the appropriate timestamp.

i got what i want on android 5.0(and above), but when i run these code on android 4.4, nothing shows up on the surface(actually i can see same picture fragment occasionally, but most of time, the surface is just black).

i tried to fill the input buffer with data fetched from file(use MediaExtractor), and it works well on both android 5.0 and 4.4.

any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the problem is the way to fetch data. i used to `get` data from native layer:

```
public static native byte[] getVideoPacket();
```

and now i `push` data from native layer to java layer:

```
env->CallVoidMethod(..., data);
```

everything just work now. i don't know why, but this way works for me.